# Graph Api - Longterm pagination for comments edge

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

For the comments edge of the facebook graph api there is only pagination based on cursor and not like most edges a timestamp pagination. The problem is that this cursors are not valid for long time. After about a day or a few minutes after a comment is deleted the cursor gets invalid and i get wrong results.

I want to somehow get all new comments from the graph api. So for feed and other edges i can save the timestamp of the last item i pulled and add since=[lastTimestamp] to the query.
Because of the short lived cursors this is not possible for comments as far as i can tell.
Did I miss something or is there any way to get comments from graph api so i dont have to page through all old comments every time?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the comment FQL table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/)?

A query could look like this.

```
SELECT id, text, time, fromid FROM comment WHERE object_id='10151309718465667' where time > {START_TIME} and time < {END_TIME}
```

Use a UNIX timestamp for {START_TIME} and {END_TIME}

Comment: That what i wanted to do first but the problem is that i have posts with far more than 5000 comments and you can never get more than the first 5000 comments from fql because time is not a index.

Comment: No error message. There is a hard limit in fql that can never return more than 5000 results to a query. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/ ["it is helpful to know that the maximum number of results we will fetch before running the visibility checks is 5,000."].

Comment: Yes, I know that, but you wrote it's because time is not an index. That's the point I dont really understand why this limit of 5000 contradicts the fact that you can pull data by using the time field...

Comment: You could theoretically also use the info of the stream.comment_info.comment_count field to partition yor request limits application-side before querying the actual comments

Comment: Fb takes 5000 comments from intern database and uses filter of time > x. but with this it can never return the 5001th comment because it can never get more than the 5000 comments from the db. same goes for groups. if a group has 20000+ members i am not able to retrieve more than the first 5000

Comment: Yeah, but the 5000 results boundary is PER REQUEST imho. So if you specify limit 0,4999 in the first query, and limit 5000, 9999 etc. what happens?

Comment: i dont get any results. it returns an empty data array as soon as i have a offset of 5000+

Comment: Do you have a public post id so I could test?

Comment: 279367092177882 is first example i found, looking for another with a comments

Comment: 308990832561153 is another example with 10k+ comments